# Unable to scroll and click, as element is not visible in selenium with native android mobile application

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, automation, appium

I am working with selenium 2.53 , Java 1.8 , Appium 1.5.3 for automation of Native mobile applications. Now i have a condition where length of page is too large and i have to click at the bottom of the page. If i do scroll page down manually while tests are running before clicking through automation- Click works fine. But i am unable to scroll down the page using code. I have tried many different code sets. right now i am trying the below code. But this as well is not working.

Now the question is: How can we scroll the page of native application to a specific element and click on that element?

```
JavascriptExecutor js = driver;
element = driver.findElement(getMethodToCall(object, byCall));
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar situation while scrolling down, and used swipe and TouchActions, both of which worked fine in my case.

**Swipe:**

```
driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration);
```

**TouchActions:**

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.press(startX, startY).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

For both these, I have used this in a loop till the time I see the object which I want to click is displayed on the screen.